# Difference between Prototype Design Pattern and simple Java clone

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, clone, prototype-pattern

I just learned that Prototype Design Pattern minimizes instance creation process. Ultimately, it calls `.clone()` method to create duplicate instance of the object.

So what is the difference between calling a normal clone method than going for Prototype Design Pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as the difference between singleton design pattern and `enum`,

One is a pattern and one is a possible **implementation** in java